# LLVM: Does PrologEpilog Insertion pass acts only on entry block

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to insert splitblock at start of a function in function pass??

Trying this results in losing stack optimization done through PrologEpilog pass on entry block.

This seem to be because of entry block getting overwritten by our splitblock code.

**Is there a way to avoid this??**

let’s say bar() and baz() has stack variable x of size 1000 defined and is of same type.

And bar() and baz() which are called in foo() are getting inlined because of optimization. We would have following observation.

**Observation:**

**In actual function foo():**
stack size calculated for foo() will be 1000+

**After adding split block at start of the foo()**
Calculated stack size for foo() will be 2000+ (1000 for bar() + 1000 for baz())
This is due to split block moving the prologue code out of entry block. This results in missing stack optimization.

**Actual function:**

```
void foo() {

entry:

call bar()
call baz()
ret void
}
```

**After split block at start of the API**

```
foo() {
entry:

%1 = call i32 @foo_test()
%2 = icmp ne i32 %1, 0, !dbg 
br i1 %2, label %if.then.block, label continue

continue:

call bar()
call baz()
ret void

if.then.block:

call foo_clone
ret void
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. You want to do X, think that necessitates Y, have a practical problem doing Y, and ask about how to do Y. Please don't do that, make X clear instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Corrected the problem statement, highlighted that I would need inputs for Y in mycase.

Comment: Ah, so you real problem is how to perform stack optimisation for functions with large stack frames. I'd never have guessed from the wording. My first suggestion is then to look at which passes exist to do the kind of optimisation you want, and try to move the inlining to before those passes.